# Edit distance for a four-digit sequential ranking in R? (stringdist)

Tags: r, edit-distance, stringdist

Right now, I am trying to create scale scores for participants who ranked four job candidates (A, B, C, and D) to a role from best fit to worst fit. The correct order is A, D, C, B. As far as my dataframe goes, the correct sequence for columns **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D** should therefore be 1, 4, 3, 2. Below is a sample of my dataframe with "**Edit_score**" representing what I *think* is degree of correctness, i.e. the degree to which the values in **Concatted** resemble "1432". I used `stringdist` in the following code to produce this column:

`data$edit_score <- stringdist("1432", data$Concatted, method = "jw")`

I am not sure if the Jaro-Winkler method is the most appropriate for this type of variable. Should I be using a different `stringdist` method? Is `stringdist` the function I should be using to calculate this? I am trying to take into account both **placement and sequence** and really just need to assign scores to **Concatted** valued based on how closely they resemble the sequence "1432".

| A | B | C | D | Concatted | Edit_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 4231 | 0.33333333 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1243 | 0.16666667 |